# Is there any way to stack JComponents in a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a class that extends `JFrame`, and I have decided to create an opening panel, a `JPanel` with 4 `JButtons`s which is added `add(initPanel)` in the constructor.

However, ideally a background image would help the `JFrame` look cleaner and decorated.

Someone on here suggested I use `setContentPane()`, and this in fact works.

However, the image appears and all the buttons/text disappear, and I can't get them to show.

I am wondering if there is any way to stack layers / `JComponent`s within a `JFrame`, so I could have my image in the background and my `JPanel` in the foreground.

Comment: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and [Simplest way to set image as JPanel background](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125707/simplest-way-to-set-image-as-jpanel-background)

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22162398/how-to-set-a-background-picture-in-jpanel/22162430#22162430), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31526190/jframe-with-background-image-and-a-jpanel/31527567#31527567), [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19631684/buttons-are-being-hidden-by-background-image/19632056#19632056)

Comment: *"I use "setContentPane()", and this in fact works. However, the image appears and all the buttons/text disappear*" - Make sure you call `setContentPane` BEFORE you try adding anything to the frame, also make sure you set the layout manager of the frame/content pane AFTER you've set it

Comment: *"so I could have my image in the background and my JPanel in the foreground."* - Also beware that `JPanel` is opaue by default